# Visual Studio express 2013 for windows desktop wont start. (Microsoft Nuget- package failed)

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-7

I am running windows 7 pro 64 bit.

I had to re-install .Net framework for a different problem and now VS won't start. I have tried to uninstall and re-install and that doesn't help. At the end of the installation is says this: [image]

It also does that when I try to repair. I re-installed my .Net frame work again and this is currently what I have:

[image]

When I try to start VS it shows up as a process in task manager for a little bit and then disappears. No window or logo ever appears

I don't know where to start with solving this problem and I am not very familiar with visual studio. Any help is appreciated

Comment: open the log files and look for more details.

Comment: Did yo restart the computer and try again as the message suggests?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Where are the log files?

Comment: @Michael Petch  yes after that I get the problem with starting it where it crashes with no window

Comment: You should be able to click the "log file" link that appears blue in your screen capture.